# Client-side not creating file

Tags: c, windows

So, I have a working socket. I'm basically making a socket to allow me to transfer files from one program to another program. Everything is working except on the client side, it won't create the file?

Server:

```
int main() {
    WSADATA Winsock;
    SOCKET Socket, Sub;
    Addr addr;
    IncomingAddress incomingAddress;
    int AddressLen = sizeof(IncomingAddress);

    // Start up Winsock
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsock);

    if (LOBYTE(Winsock.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(Winsock.wVersion) != 2) {
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    // Memset alternative
    ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(Addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
    bind(Socket, (sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(Addr));

    if (listen(Socket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Listening error!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Listening...\n");
    }

    if (Sub = accept(Socket, (sockaddr*) &incomingAddress, &AddressLen)) {
        char *ClientIP = inet_ntoa(incomingAddress.sin_addr);
        int ClientPort = ntohs(incomingAddress.sin_port);
        printf("Client connected!\n");
        printf("IP: %s:%d\n", ClientIP, ClientPort);

        printf("Sending file... \n");

        FILE *File;
        char *Buffer;
        unsigned long Size;

        File = fopen("test.txt", "rb+");
        if (!File) {
            printf("Error while reading the file!\n");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }

        fseek(File, 0, SEEK_END);
        Size = ftell(File);
        fseek(File, 0, SEEK_SET);

        Buffer = malloc(Size);

        fread(Buffer, Size, 1, File);
        char cSize[MAX_PATH];
        sprintf(cSize, "%i", Size);

        fclose(File);
        send(Sub, cSize, MAX_PATH, 0); // File size
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
int main() {
    WSADATA Winsock;
    SOCKET Socket;
    Addr addr;
    IncomingAddress incomingAddress;
    int AddressLen = sizeof(IncomingAddress);

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsock);

    if (LOBYTE(Winsock.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(Winsock.wVersion) != 2) {
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(Addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(6000);

    if (connect(Socket, (sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(Addr)) < 0) {
        printf("Connection Failed!\n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Connection successful! \n");
    printf("Receiving file... \n");

    int Size;
    char *Filesize = malloc(1024);

    if (recv(Socket, Filesize, 1024, 0)) { // File Size
        Size = atoi((const char*) Filesize);
        printf("File size: %d\n", Size);
    }

    char *Buffer = malloc(Size);

    int Offset = 0;
    while (Size > Offset) {
        int Amount = recv(Socket, Buffer + Offset, Size - Offset, 0);

        if (Amount <= 0) {
            printf("Error: " + WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        } else {
            Offset += Amount;
            printf("2\n");
        }
    }

    FILE *File;
    File = fopen("test.txt", "wb+");
    fwrite(Buffer, 1, Size, File);
    fclose(File);

    getchar();
    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One obvious mistake is that you don't send the actual file in the "server" code. Make sure you check the return code of every library function and sprinkle your code with debugging messages, then you'll be on your way learning to program! Most programming environments also have debuggers, which can help a lot.

Comment: Your server does only send the file size, not the file content, so the client is waiting in a `recv` call in the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I am such an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending merely the lenght of the file, but not the file itself to the client:

```
    send(Sub, cSize, MAX_PATH, 0); // File size
```

This never recieves anything:

```
    int Amount = recv(Socket, Buffer + Offset, Size - Offset, 0);
```

So yeah, just send the actual file as well.